# How can I fetch the artist and song title from Azuracast API and display it in my Javascript/JSX internet radio player?

Tags: javascript

I have a Internet Radio Player built in javascript specifically javascript with JSX (javascript/html) files and it fetches data from a list of radios. The player currently displays the image of the station, station title and genre from the list I've created. I want to fetch the "artist & song title" from the icecast channels I'm using, but have no idea how I would do this. I'm using Azuracast to broadcast the radios and it has an API json system to fetch any of the data I want. I have no idea how to get that data to the .jsx file displaying the artist and title in the player.

Logo of Station
Station Name
Genre
(would like artist & song title here)
Play button

Comment: have you heard of the term *AJAX* regarding web applications and API's?